# C++ 11 - Pass a reference as a constructor argument for ownership

Tags: c++11, pass-by-reference, delete-operator

I'm fairly new C++ and so I may not be using the correct terminology. Here is what I'm looking to do.

I have classes `Foo` and `Bar`. 
I'd like to create an instance of `Foo`.
then I'd like to create an instance of `Bar` and pass the `Foo` instance to the constructor of `Bar` such that `Bar` now owns the lifetime of `Foo`. Such that when `Bar's` destructor is call, it will/should de-allocate the `Foo` instance.

Also, I'd like to make it obvious (using the correct C++ semantics) to the user's of `Foo` and `Bar`, that Bar owns the Foo instance.

I'm open to any advise/best practice suggestions as well.

Here is my attempt at this. What feels wrong to me is the `delete &m_foo;` in Bar's destructor. I also don't understand what `:m_foo(foo)` is really doing in Bar's ctor (and what is it called exactly - how would I speak it?). I would have thought making an assignment in the constructor would be correct.

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo();
    ~Foo();
private:

};

Foo::Foo()
{
}

Foo::~Foo()
{
}

class Bar
{
public:
    Bar(Foo & foo);
    ~Bar();
private:
    Foo & m_foo;

};

Bar::Bar(Foo & foo)
    :m_foo(foo)
{
}

Bar::~Bar()
{
    delete &m_foo;
}
```

Here is How I'd like to use it

```
int main()
{
    auto foo = new Foo();
    auto bar = new Bar(*foo);
    delete bar;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proper way to do this is with `std::unique_ptr`:

```
#include <memory>


class Foo
{
public:
    Foo() {}
    ~Foo() {}
private:

};

class Bar
{
public:
    Bar(std::unique_ptr<Foo> foo);
    ~Bar()
    {
       // m_foo will be destroyed at the end, and the Foo object
       // that m_foo points to will be destroyed as well.
    }
private:
    std::unique_ptr<Foo> m_foo;

};

Bar::Bar(std::unique_ptr<Foo> foo)
    // This section after the colon and before the open brace
    // is the member initializer list. This defines what
    // arguments are passed to the constructors of the members.
    : m_foo(std::move(foo))
        // std::move is required here to make it clear that
        // you are transferring ownership to the member.  It
        // causes the move constructor to be used instead of
        // the copy constructor.
{
}

int main()
{
    Bar bar(std::unique_ptr<Foo>(new Foo));
    return 0;
}
```

You'll have to access the member as a pointer rather than as a reference.

With C++14, you'd want to use `std::make_unique` to construct your `Foo` pointer, but since this is a C++11 question, I've used `new`.

Comment: Yes, I would have loved to use the `std::unique_ptr` feature, but I believe this is a C++ 14 feature, no? I'm not able to use this feature in the environment/tool chain I'm using (embedded).

Comment: std::unique_ptr is a C++11 feature, whereas std::make_unique is a C++14 feature. Edit: I see you are using C++11, you can simply use the std::unique_ptr constructor in-place of std::make_unique despite being less safe.

Comment: @ShivKumar: The only difference with C++11 is that you don't have `std::make_unique`.  You can write your own or use new instead.  I've updated my answer to not use `std::make_unique`.

Comment: I'm using the Particle Photon (micro controller). I'm guessing it's probably a subset of C++ 11 then. I can include <memory> but it doesn't like ...`'make_unique' is not a member of 'std'`.

Comment: @VaughnCato, ahh, I see my mistake. Let me try your suggestion.

Comment: Yes, this complies!! Thank you.

Comment: @VaughnCato, would you mind updating your answer to include the answer to my question about `:m_foo(std::move(foo))`. What is this doing exactly? Why is it "before" the constructor? How would I say/speak this?

Comment: @ShivKumar:  I've added some comments.  See if that helps.

Comment: @VaughnCato thank you, yes those comments help. So if I understand this correctly. the private member `m_foo` is constructed literally with an instance of the `foo` passed in? So does that mean the copy constructor for `Foo` is being used here?

Comment: @ShivKumar: It is actually the move constructor, but it is similar.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151788/discussion-between-vaughn-cato-and-shiv-kumar).